# Update some files from a local non hg dir to an hg server without needing to clone the online copy

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to Mercurial.

I downloaded a copy of a BitBucket repo via it's zip option but now I need to make changes to this copy, so is it possible to use this downloaded zip contents and somehow link it to the online hg copy, so I can make the changes and push the changed files without needing to re-download all the files.

FYI the the repo is over 1GB big and my Internet is capped so I am trying to avoid downloading it again (via clone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you downloaded - but probably the answer is no.

I'm assuming that the zip file you downloaded from bitbucket was just the latest source code - i.e. you used the `get source` link on the right hand side of the menu tabs and selected `zip`.

If that's the case, then what you have is a copy of the latest source code, but you don't actually have

> a copy of a BitBucket repo

In order to push changes back to the mercurial repository you need to actually have a real mercurial clone, not just a copy of the latest source code.

If you actually had a copy of the repo (which would mean you had downloaded the actual history of the changes to the project) then you could do what you are asking, but I don't think bitbucket has any way to download that as a zip file.

As far as I can see, the only choices you have now are:

1. Clone the repository from scratch
2. Just make changes to the code you have downloaded, and send the changes to the maintainer as a regular patch, rather than a mercurial changeset.